# PPTPD on lxd unprivileged container

Tags: lxd, pptp, unprivileged

There is lxd-3.0.3 unprivileged (containers with uid shift started by root) on 
Ubuntu-18.04 (amd64). In container there is Ubuntu-16.04.5 (amd64).
How to configure pptpd on it? It seems that there is problem with ppp0 interface. It is not available.

Here if fragment of log:

```
Feb 13 19:21:22 blabla100 pppd[25943]: Plugin /usr/lib/pptpd/pptpd-logwtmp.so loaded.
Feb 13 19:21:22 blabla100 pppd[25943]: Couldn't open the /dev/ppp device: No such file or directory
Feb 13 19:21:22 blabla100 pptpd[25927]: modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/
Feb 13 19:21:22 blabla100 pptpd[25927]: modprobe: FATAL: Module ppp_generic not found in directory /lib/modules
Feb 13 19:21:27 blabla100 pptpd[25927]: /usr/sbin/pppd: You need to create the /dev/ppp device node by
Feb 13 19:21:27 blabla100 pptpd[25927]: executing the following command as root:
Feb 13 19:21:27 blabla100 pptpd[25927]:         mknod /dev/ppp c 108 0
Feb 13 19:21:27 blabla100 pppd[25935]: You need to create the /dev/ppp device node by
                                    executing the following command as root:
                                            mknod /dev/ppp c 108 0
```

So I guess I must create /dev/ppp on host, but how to allow to access it only in this container, not other containers.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Right now, your question lacks any helpful description. The good thing is, you can simply [edit] your question and include as much description as you like. Please take the time to explain what you are doing where you hit a problem. Please read [about] and [ask] before asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

The Unix character device `/dev/ppp` on the host is the way you can access the kernel module for `ppp.ko`. Therefore, you need to get LXD to link that character device into the LXD container. Here is how it's done:

```
$ lxc config device add mypptpcontainer mypppdevice unix-char source=/dev/ppp uid=0 gid=0 mode=0600
```

where:

1. `mypptpcontainer` is the name of your LXD container.
2. `mypppdevice` is just a name for this LXD device. Pick any name.
3. the rest specify the characteristics of the unix character device.